# batch file rename files in folder

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I have multiple text files in a folder that I am searching the content for and renaming the found files but having a problem. When I run the batch it renames all the found files to the same filename. So if it finds 3 files with the string in them it renames all of them to the same file. Still kinda new to this stuff. I am trying to find the string "test1" inside all the text files and then rename the files found to test1.txt, test1 (2).txt, etc.

```
@ECHO OFF
@SETLOCAL enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

SET "sourcedir=C:\test"
SET "searchfor=test1"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('findstr /m /L /c:"%searchfor%" "%sourcedir%\*.txt"') DO (
 REN "%%a" "%searchfor%.txt"
)
```

Comment: Before `REN`aming you're going to have to add a counter, _probably using `SET /A`_, and then use an `IF\ELSE` expression with `EXIST`.

Comment: its not an answer to your question but you should use `('findstr /m /L /c:"\<%searchfor%\>" "%sourcedir%\*.txt"')` to avoid words containing test1 but not just test1

Comment: @UlugToprak, when stipulating **`/L`** the regular expressions **`\<`** and **`\>`** should be seen as literal characters and fail to match the intended string.

Answer (score 2):

change

```
 REN "%%a" "%searchfor%.txt"
```

to

```
 if exist "%searchfor%.txt" (
  set "renamed="
  for /L %%r in (1,1,100) do if not defined renamed if not exist "%searchfor% (%%r).txt" REN "%%a" "%searchfor% (%%r).txt"&set "renamed=%%r"

  ) else (
  REN "%%a" "%searchfor%.txt"
 )
```

which will for each filename-to-be-changed first detect whether %searchfor%.txt exists, and rename the target file if not. If %searchfor%.txt exists, then set the `renamed` flag to *nothing* and loop for `%%r` = 1 to 100 by steps of 1. If the filename `%searchfor% (%%r).txt` does not exist, then do the rename and set `renamed` to (well - any value other than *nothing* will do - `%%r` is convenient). Since `renamed` is now defined,  `if not defined` will be false, so no further rename attempts will be made for that target filename.

(untested)

Note - the syntax is important. Don't try to break the statements over many lines or alter the positions of the parentheses. Just cut-and-paste.

Tip:

Instead of `ren` use `echo ren` which will simply REPORT the proposed rename. Obviously, since the file won't actually be renamed, the procedure will report the same new name. Then manually create `%searchfor%.txt` and try again. Then manually create `%searchfor% (1).txt` and try yet again. You'll see the proposed new name change. After testing in this manner, change each `echo ren` to `ren` and all should proceed smoothly.

(perform tests on a copy with a small number of "hits" to avoid confusion)

Comment: hi, is possible that, in loop, every echo test report only, and ending normally,  but, if crop out echo from ren, when command, the files *.txt will adding to queuing, this will increase, and loop will do in all "old", and "new" txt file, without ending? sorry my limited English, hope do you understand this comment..

Comment: @kaputtz First, `findstr` will create a list of the required filenames from the directory *as it is* **at the current time**. The `for /f` waits for the list to be built, then processes that list, so the renames are performed using the filenames as they were originally. If a file is renamed, then the list created by `findstr` cannot contain the *new* filename because the *new* filename did not exist when the `findstr` was executed, so the *renamed* file will not be perpetually renamed.

Comment: @kaputtz : Note however, that if files `name`, `name(1)` and `name(2)` exist, and each of those files contains the string `name` then 1. `name` will be renamed `name(3)` (as this is the first `name(?)` that does not already exist ,) 2. `name(1)` will be then be renamed `name` as `name` no longer exists and then 3. `name(2)` will be renamed `name(1)` as `name(1)` no longer exists.

Comment: Thank you for comment/answer me!